# Python bug import csv file for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file with the specified encoding
df = pd.read_csv("Moodle/perguntas_1.csv", encoding = 'utf-8')

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```

It doesn't import the csv file into a dataframe.
The following error appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Carlos-DESKTOP\Documents\Universidade\Licenciatura - Eng.ª Informática\1º Ano\2º Semestre\Laboratório de programação\moodle_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("Moodle/perguntas_1.csv", encoding = 'utf-8')
  File "C:\Users\Carlos-DESKTOP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1026, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos-DESKTOP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 626, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos-DESKTOP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1923, in read
    ) = self._engine.read(  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "C:\Users\Carlos-DESKTOP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 234, in read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "parsers.pyx", line 838, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "parsers.pyx", line 905, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "parsers.pyx", line 874, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "parsers.pyx", line 891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._check_tokenize_status
  File "parsers.pyx", line 2061, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

import this csv file into a dataframe with the pandas library.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have a COMMA separated file? `Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2` This suggests two things: 1) file reader tries to split by commas and receives 1 column for rows 1 and 2 (when we clearly see more) 2) `questao` in row 3 has a comma which is not properly handled in your file how it would typically be in csv file

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and it's not clear what you need help with. If you want to ask why you're getting this error, we'll need to see the actual CSV data (plain text, [not a picture](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341)). It looks like you opened the CSV file with Excel, and IIRC, Excel uses some magic to figure out how to parse CSVs, so the screenshot doesn't really tell us anything. For more tips, check out [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is likely due to a discrepancy in the number of columns expected by `pandas` while reading your CSV file compared to what it finds on line 3 of your file. This kind of error **typically** arises in situations where the CSV file uses a delimiter that is different from the default value of `","`.

To address this issue, you can try the following approaches:

1. **Specifying the correct delimiter**: Check the delimiter used in your CSV file. If the file uses a different delimiter (such as a semicolon `;`, tab `\t`, or space  ), you need to specify it using the `sep` parameter. Looking at the image you've provided, it seems you're working with data written in Portuguese and the default delimiter in Brazil for example is `";"` instead of ",". To visually check your delimiter, you could use a code like this:

   ```py
   with open("Moodle/perguntas_1.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
       text = fh.read()
       print(text)
   ```

   If in fact the file is not using `","` as delimiter, but instead `";"` you could specify it to `pandas.read_csv` like so:

   ```py
   df = pd.read_csv("Moodle/perguntas_1.csv", encoding='utf-8', sep=';')
   ```
2. **Handling irregular number of columns**: If the issue is due to irregular numbers of columns across rows and you want to ignore these discrepancies, you can set the parameter `on_bad_lines` to `"skip"` and skip the bad lines. Optionally, if you want pandas to warn you about which lines were skipped, you can set the parameter `on_bad_lines` to `"warn"`. Here's an example on how to skip and warn about bad lines while reading a CSV file:

   ```py
   on_bad_lines="warn")
   df = pd.read_csv("Moodle/perguntas_1.csv", encoding='utf-8', on_bad_lines="skip")
   ```

### Notes

You could also try to force pandas to infer the correct delimiter of your CSV file, by setting the parameter `sep` from `pandas.read_csv` to `None` like so:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("Moodle/perguntas_1.csv", encoding='utf-8', sep=None, engine='python')
```

Beware that the above solution is much slower than if you specified the correct delimiter and used the default *C* engine. It might also not work if you have conflicting delimiters in your CSV file.